# Rigid body settings to a group as a whole

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, groups

I would like to apply rigid body physics to a grouped set of objects, but would not like that set of objects to be dismantled during the simulation (preserving their relative positions).

For example, imagine two spheres forming a "water molecule":

[image]

And I want to bounce such molecules in my simulation without breaking them apart. How do I go about doing that in Blender?

Answer (score -1):

Join objects together. Select objects you want to join then press Ctrl+J.

Comment: This can actually work, but I'm looking for a solution which involves keeping the objects separate...